# Trouble with Tkinter event handler inside of a class

Tags: python, class, event-handling, tkinter

My problem is that I have a class that creates a Tkinter topclass object and then puts a field into it and I want to add an event handler that runs a method (that is also in the class) every time a button is pressed but when the event is called it says

> AttributeError: Toplevel instance has no attribute 'updateSearch'

```
class EditStudentWindow():

def __init__(self):

    searchResultList = ['student1', 'student2', 'student3'] # test list

    ##### window attributes

    # create window
    self = Tkinter.Toplevel()

    #window title
    self.title('Edit Students')

    ##### puts stuff into the window

    # text
    editStudentInfoLabel = Tkinter.Label(self,text='Select the student from the list below or search for one in the search box provided')
    editStudentInfoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # entry box
    searchRepositoryEntry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
    searchRepositoryEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)

    # list box
    searchResults = Tkinter.Listbox(self)
    searchResults.grid(row=2, column=0)

    ##### event handler
```

> right here

```
    searchRepositoryEntry.bind('<Key>',command = self.updateSearch)
    # search results

    for result in searchResultList:
        searchResults.insert(Tkinter.END, result)

def updateSearch(self, event):
    print('foo')
```

Comment: What do you think `self = Tkinter.Toplevel()` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging solely on the indentation of your example, it appears that updateSearch is indeed not part of the class definition.

Assuming the indentation is a markup mistake, and based on the error message you report, the other problem is that you redefine `self`, so 'self.updateSearch' points to the toplevel rather than the EditStudentWindow class. Note that the message says `Toplevel instance has no attribute 'updateSearch'` rather than `EditStudentWindow instance...`

Typically, such widgets are created with inheritance rather than composition. You might want to consider refactoring your code to look something like:

```
class EditStudentWindowClass(Tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Edit Students')
        ...
```

Comment: I tried adding the inheritance and it still says toplevel doesn't have the attribute and yes it is a markup mistake I double checked and the code is indented

Comment: @Brandon: you have done something wrong. I cut and pasted your code, changed it to do the inheritance like I suggested while leaving other code as is (and properly commenting out the `self=Tkinter.Toplevel`), and properly created a root window, and your code works fine (well, I also had to remove the `command=` in your binding, which tells me this code isn't your actual code or you would have gotten errors)

Comment: Sorry, when I added the inheritance I forgot to add the 'Tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self)' and then the 'command=' error came up it is all now working  thank you for you help